# How to pass the examples from excel file for scenario outline

Tags: cucumber

In BDD specflow we have the feature to pass the scenario outline examples from excel as below

```
Feature: ExcelTestFeature
        test transform of excel data into dictionary

Scenario Outline: Multiline Data
                  Given data converts to "<one>", "<two>" dictionary

 @source:Testdata.xlsx:Sheet1
 Examples:
 |ono|two|
```

Do we have equivalent code for  **@source:Testdata.xlsx:Sheet1** in cucumber bdd?

Note: I need to solution in cucumber on in qmetry automation framework

Comment: I dont think there is an equivalent in cucumber. Cucumber recommends to have data build into feature file using datatable or example tables. However using external datasheet as a datatable is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **cucumber with java** you can add [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#how-to-use) dependency. Then you can add data provider meta-data to your scenario as example below:

```
@dataFile:Testdata.xlsx @sheetName:Sheet1
Scenario Outline: Multiline Data
      Given data converts to "<one>", "<two>" dictionary
```